# How do I count rows with matching id?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm currently having some difficulty with determining if any rows match a specific user id. The code runs fine, but the if statement (if($notifs !== false) always returns true and hence "No notifications found" never displays. How do I write the statement to only check for "receive_id" that match the current session id?

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['userID'];

if(isset($_POST["view"]))
{

$stmt = $user_notif->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$user_id));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $user_notif->runQuery("SELECT * FROM notif_follow WHERE receive_id= ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
$stmt->bindValue(1,$user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$notifs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$notification = '';

if($notifs !== false)
 {
  foreach($notifs as $notif)
  {

  $send_id = $notif['send_id'];

  $query2 = $user_notif->runQuery("SELECT id FROM following WHERE user1_id=:uid1 AND user2_id=:uid2");
  $query2->execute(array(":uid1"=>$user_id,":uid2"=>$send_id));
  $query2result = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if($query2result !== false){
  $follow .= '<a href="followoff.php?id='.$send_id.'"><button class="button">Remove Channel</button></a>';
  }
  else{
  $follow .= '<a href="followon.php?id='.$send_id.'"><button class="button">Add Channel</button></a>';
  }

  $notification .= '
   <li>
     <div class="notifbox">
     <strong style="color: #4b8ed3;">'.$notif["send_name"].'</strong><p style="color: #fff;"> has added you.</p>

     '.$follow.'

&nbsp<a href="index.php?id='.$notif["send_id"].'"><button class="button">View Channel</button></a>
     </div>
   </li>
   <div class="sectionheader3"></div>
   ';

  }
 }
 else
 {
  $notification .= '<li><h2 style="color: #4b8ed3; padding: 10px;">No Notifications Found<h2></li>';
 }
```

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `!== false`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchAll` only returns `false` if the query failed, but it's not failing. The result is an array. Your best to check if `count($notifs) > 0` and also if `$notifs === false` for the possibility of the query failing.

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php says:

> An empty array is returned if there are zero results to fetch, or FALSE on failure.

A query that matches zero rows is not a failure. It's a success at giving you the information that there are zero matching rows.

So you shouldn't compare with `$notifs !== false`, which compares exactly to the boolean `false`. You might like to compare with:

```
if (!$notifs)
```

This will also test for the empty array.

Comment: If the query failed, it does not mean there are zero rows that were found. There should be three conditions to check for... one or more rows were found, zero rows were found and the query failed.

Comment: @ub3rst4r, I tend to enable PDO exceptions anyway, so that's one check that would not be necessary in code.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if ($stmt->RowCount() > 0) {
$notifs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//code here
}
```

Instead of

```
$notifs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($notifs !== false) {
//code here
}
```